# efficient discrete bayes filter for localization

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization, bayesian

I'm trying to implement a discrete bayes filter (i.e. histogram filter) for robot localization as described in 'Probabilistic Robotics' by Thrun, Burgard, and Fox. The model is a robot that moves in one dimensions, so the state vector is just the position and velocity. At each time step there is a random acceleration with mean of zero and variance of one.

I think that my implementation is accurate, but it runs slowly. I'm looping over indices of my probability density map which seems very inefficient, but I don't see how to vectorize this algorithm correctly. Any suggestions?

My code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from math import pi, exp, sqrt
import matplotlib.cm as cm

N = 31
numsteps = 5

# set up grid
x = np.linspace(-10, 10, N)
v = np.linspace(-10, 10, N)
sp = (x[1] - x[0])/2
X, V = np.meshgrid(x, v)

# initial probability distribution is a delta function at origin
p0 = np.zeros(X.shape)
p0[N/2, N/2] = 1
plt.ion()
plt.imshow(p0, cmap = cm.Greys_r, interpolation='none')
plt.draw()

acc_var = 1 # Variance of random acceleration

for ii in range(numsteps):
    print 'Step %d'%ii
    p1 = np.zeros(X.shape)
    for (i, j), p in np.ndenumerate(p0): #outer loop over configuration space
        for (k,l), x in np.ndenumerate(X):
            # new position is old position plus velocity
            if X[i,j] > X[k,l] + V[k,l] - sp and X[i,j] <= X[k,l] + V[k,l] + sp: 
                # Bayesian update with random acceleration
                p1[i,j] = p1[i,j] + exp(-0.5 * (V[i,j] - V[k,l])**2 / acc_var) / sqrt(2*pi*acc_var) * p0[k,l] 
    p0 = p1
    plt.imshow(p1, cmap = cm.Greys_r, interpolation='none')
    plt.draw()
```

Comment: is this code correct? it seems that only the last execution of `p1[i,j] =` will be saved at position `i, j`

Comment: I think it's correct. The results look reasonable. I'm keeping a cumulative sum at position i,j.

Comment: so perhaps it should be `p1[i,j] +=`